# artisan db:seed doesn't work on development evnironment, works fine in local

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I have the following in my db seeder
        Eloquent::unguard();

```
    DB::statement("SET foreign_key_checks = 0");

    $this->call('TruncateTablesSeeder');
    $this->command->info('Trancated all tables!');

    $this->call('RoleTableSeeder');
    $this->command->info('Roles table seeded!');

    $this->call('ModuleTableSeeder');
    $this->command->info('Modules table seeded!');

    $this->call('UserTableSeeder');
    $this->command->info('User table seeded!');
    $this->command->info('Super admin created!');

    DB::statement("SET foreign_key_checks = 1");
```

Module Seeder

```
    DB::table('modules')->truncate();
    //Module::create(array('name' => 'dashboard', 'is_active' => '1'));
    Module::create(array('name' => 'accountsetup', 'is_active' => '1'));
    Module::create(array('name' => 'managecomponent', 'is_active' => '1'));     
    Module::create(array('name' => 'managescenario', 'is_active' => '1'));     
    Module::create(array('name' => 'variancereport', 'is_active' => '1'));     
    Module::create(array('name' => 'synchronization', 'is_active' => '1'));
```

All seeders are of a similar nature

When I run db:seed in local, it works fine.

When I use it in development server, it doesn't give any output, just keeps running forever

Also, here's how I load the environment:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function(){
    return file_get_contents(__DIR__."/../environment");
});
```

There's a file called environment in app which has the environment name : local, development, etc...

Comment: Are your database settings for development DB set correctly?

Comment: App::environment() is a much easier way to get the environment btw

Comment: The DB Settings are correct. The frontend works fine. No error btw. Just infinite hang time

Comment: @JeremyGehrs App:environment() gives the current environment. This code is used for setting it.

Comment: Any errors or additional info in the laravel log?  tail -f app/storage/logs/laravel.log